# React - JSX is not changing on conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, components

I am doing a conditional rendering in my code in which i need to change the component called according to the state when it changes every time. Default option is Unpaid. When I select Paid 1st time state changes to the paid and component also changes to paid but after that if I changes to Unpaid state is changing but the Component is stuck to Paid. What can be the issue? Code is attached.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Paid from "./Paid";
import Unpaid from "./Unpaid";

const Payment = () => {
    const [paid, setPaid] = useState(0);

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="container">
                <br />
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-4">
                        <select
                            className="browser-default custom-select"
                            onChange={(option) => setPaid(option.target.value)}
                            required
                        >
                            <option value="0">Unpaid</option>

                            <option value="1">Paid</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-8"></div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>{paid ? <Paid /> : <Unpaid />}</div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Payment;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse `option.target.value`, as it's always evaluating to `true` since inputs always output a string, which is always truthy.

```
onChange={(option) => setPaid(JSON.parse(option.target.value))}
```

Answer (score 1):

add `+` to convert the string value to a number `0` or `1`

```
 onChange={(option) =>{let val=+option.target.value ;setPaid(val);}}
```

```js
let a="0"
let b="1"

console.log(+a,+b)
let c=+a
 c? console.log("test 1"):console.log("test 2")
```

Comment: Great answer. Using the `+` operator is an excellent shorthand approach.

Comment: I use it to avoid using `parseFloat` or `parseInt` but if it not evaluated at place like `+a? console.log("test 1"):console.log("test 2")` for that you should assign it to another variable then use that variable

Answer (score 0):

Look this way to update your state

```
({ target: { value } }) => setPaid(value)
```